# In-app purchases: how and where are purchases stored? (Android, iOS)

Tags: android, ios

I am aware that apple provides a store for in-app purchases and any user can pull that data from different devices. Is there such a provision for Android apps (Google Market or Amazon App Store)? If so, how do we use this? I've not been able to find any info abt this online. I'm afraid I might have to store purchase information in my own DB. Would that be okay? Anything I need to be aware of?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Market provides a RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request which returns to you a list of all the (managed) purchases made by the user.  You can issue this request on a new install to get the user's list of purchases.

It is very similar to restoring purchases for the iOS in-app purchases.

It only works for managed purchases which means purchases that the user owns forever.

You will still need some kind of local list of purchases as Google recommends you only do RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS on new installs.